# Get Numbers & Pages et al. on macOS 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, pages, numbers, iwork

I have some old macs which cannot update to OSX 10.12, however this is the minimum requirement for installing those applications from the app store. Please could someone advise how to get an older, compatible version of this software legally through Apple? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind going back a few versions and spending a bit of money, iWork '09 can still be purchased: https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MB942Z-A-iWork-09/dp/B0014X2UAK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1502548992&sr=8-1&keywords=iwork (See the used options for significantly lower costs)

Comment: I also do have this problem. I'm on a older MBP running Sierra 10.12.6 and need an previous version of Numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue too. Whenever I used an Apple ID that hadn't previously downloaded iWork I wasn't able to download the free version on 10.11. I even tried [this workaround](https://www.cultofmac.com/306118/download-apples-iwork-apps-older-macs-free/).

What did work was getting access to a 10.12 Mac. Downloading Pages, Numbers and Keynote. The apps were now associated to that Apple ID. I then went back to the 10.11 Mac's, signed in using the same ID and clicked download. The App Store displayed a message asking if I would like to download an older compatible version.

Comment: +1 Wow. this worked! Shame on apple. They should let you download an older version by default. I have a late 2011 mbp. Updating to Sierra will not only slow down my laptop further, but the hardware itself doesn't support 90% of the updates that Sierra has to offer. Smh..

Comment: I've just tried to install them on a Mac with OS X El Capitan (10.11.6) and I wasn't offered any older version but Mac App Store simply refused installation (the apps require macOS 10.13+). That's life with digital app stores. :-(